# ERROR in Template execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'polyfills' of undefined

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I am migrating form webpack 4 to webpack 5 version and after following documentation, getting below error

ERROR in Template execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'polyfills' of undefined

```
ERROR in   TypeError: Cannot read property 'polyfills' of undefined
  
  - index.html:15 
    /Users/lovecoder/Sites/ORG/UI-Folder/src/index.html:15:42
  
  - index.html:26 MFLM.module.exports
    /Users/lovecoder/Sites/ORG/UI-Folder/src/index.html:26:3
  
  - index.js:406 
    [UI-Folder]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:406:16
  
  - runMicrotasks
  
  - task_queues.js:97 processTicksAndRejections
    internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
  
  - async Promise.all
```

below is my webpack.config.js file:

```
const path = require("path");
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const webpack = require("webpack");
// __webpack_base_uri__ = 'http://localhost:8080';
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
//const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
//const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require("moment-locales-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const baseWebpackConfig = require("./webpack.config.base");
//const EmitterWebpackPLugin = require("../src/EmitterWebpackPlugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const config = require("config");
const signInBuild = require("./signPages.dev.config.json")
const host = config.get("host") || "/";
const sourceMapHost = config.get("sourceMapHost") || "";
const sourceMapType =  config.get("sourceMapType") || "inline-cheap-module-source-map"
const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require("preload-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPluginCrossorigin = require('html-webpack-plugin-crossorigin');
//let LodashModuleReplacementPlugin = require("lodash-webpack-plugin");

const CleanObsoleteChunks = require("webpack-clean-obsolete-chunks");

console.log("Environment is : ", process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log("app will build at:" + config.get("appPath"));
console.log("Source map type is:" + sourceMapType);


const GLOBALS = {
    "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    },
    __DEV__: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(process.env.DEBUG || "false")),
    __STUBS__: false
};


function injectSiginPages() {
    var arr = [];
    
        arr.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            filename: "sign-in.pug",
            template: "./src/StaticPage/sign-in.html",
            chunksSortMode: "none"
        }));
    
    if (signInBuild.buildLegacySignInPage) {
        arr.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            filename: "sign-in-legacy.pug",
            template: "./src/StaticPage/legacy/sign-in-legacy.html",
            chunksSortMode: "none"
        }))
    }

    if (signInBuild.buildForgetPassword) {
        console.log("buildForgetPassword");
        arr.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            filename: "forgot-password.pug",
            template: "./src/StaticPage/forgot-password.html",
            chunksSortMode: "none"
        }))
    }

    if (signInBuild.buildResetPassword) {
        console.log("buildResetPassword");
        arr.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: false,
            filename: "reset-password.pug",
            template: "./src/StaticPage/reset-password.html",
            chunksSortMode: "none"
        }))
    }
    
    if (signInBuild.buildSiginInPageHTML) {
        arr.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: path.join(__dirname, "../src/StaticPage/commonhtml"),
                to: "commonhtml"

            }
        ]))
    }


    return arr;


}

function injectMobileUnsupportedPages() {
    var arr = [];

    arr.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: false,
        filename: "mobile-unsupported.pug",
        template: "./src/StaticPage/mobile/unsupported/index.html",
        chunksSortMode: "none"
    }))

    return arr;
}

module.exports = (env = {}) => {
    const productionWebpackConfig = {};
    // common plugins for demo and prod
    const plugins = [
        //new LodashModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new MomentLocalesPlugin(),

        // Avoid publishing files when compilation fails
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            minimize: true,
            debug: false
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/app.[contenthash].min.css",
            ignoreOrder: true
            // allChunks: true
        })
        //@need to  be checked

        /* new PreloadWebpackPlugin() */
    ];

    // demo environment - for faster builds and no uglify
    if (process.env.NO_UGLIFY) {

        console.log("\n********  This is demo build - to be used in local environment only *******\n");
        console.log("devtool is", sourceMapType)
        Object.assign(productionWebpackConfig, {
            devtool: sourceMapType
        });

        plugins.push(
            // new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                filename: "index.pug",
                template: "./src/index.html",
                chunksSortMode: "none"
            }),
            ...injectSiginPages(),

            /*  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
                generateStatsFile: true
            }), */
            // new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin(),
            new CleanObsoleteChunks({
                verbose: true,
                deep: true
            })
           
        );
    } else {

        // for prod environment only
        console.log("\n******** This is actual prod build - to be deployed on demo and prod environment ********\n");
        plugins.push(
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, "../src/vendor/drift.js"),
                    to: "js/vendor"
                },
                {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, "../src/assets/images/copy-images"),
                    to: "images/copied-images"
                },
                {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, "../src/app/staticAsset"),
                    to: "staticAsset"
                },
                {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, "../src/StaticPage/resources/css"),
                    to: "StaticPage/css"
                },
                {
                    from: path.join(__dirname, "../src/StaticPage/commonhtml"),
                    to: "commonhtml"

                }
            ]),
            new CompressionPlugin({
                /* filename(asset) {//renaming is required because in main application PHP calls these files like this ( see web2/index.php for reference)
                    return asset.replace(".js.gz", ".gz.js").replace(".css.gz", ".gz.css");
                }, */
                algorithm: "gzip",
                test: /\.(js|html|css)$/
            }),
            
            // new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
           
            
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                filename: "index.pug",
                template: "./src/index.html",
                chunksSortMode: "none",
                attributes: {
                    crossorigin: 'anonymous'
                }
            }),
            
           
           
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                filename: "forgot-password.pug",
                template: "./src/StaticPage/forgot-password.html",
                chunksSortMode: "none"
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                filename: "reset-password.pug",
                template: "./src/StaticPage/reset-password.html",
                chunksSortMode: "none"
            }),
             ...injectMobileUnsupportedPages(),

            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                filename: "sign-in-legacy.pug",
                template: "./src/StaticPage/legacy/sign-in-legacy.html",
                chunksSortMode: "none"
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                filename: "sign-in.pug",
                template: "./src/StaticPage/sign-in.html",
                chunksSortMode: "none"
            }),
           
            new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
                rel: 'prefetch',
                include: 'allChunks',
                excludeHtmlNames: ['index.pug'],

            }), 

           
            /*  new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
                generateStatsFile: true
            }), */
            // new webpack.ExtendedAPIPlugin(),
            
             
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: "[file].map",
                append: `\n//# sourceMappingURL=${sourceMapHost}/[url]`
            }),
            // new CleanWebpackPlugin([config.get("appPath")], {
            //     allowExternal: true
            // })
            //new EmitterWebpackPLugin(),
        );

        Object.assign(productionWebpackConfig, {
            optimization: {
                minimizer: [
                    new UglifyJsPlugin({
                        exclude: 'prefetchSW.js',
                        uglifyOptions: {
                            cache: true,
                            parallel: true,
                            warnings: false,
                            output: {
                                comments: false
                            },
    
                            exclude: 'prefetchSW.js',
                           
                            chunkFilter: (chunk) => {
                                // Exclude uglification for the these chunks
                                if (chunk.name === "vendor" || chunk.name === "application" || chunk.name === "extras"|| chunk.name === "prefetchSW") {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                ]
            }
        });

    }

    Object.assign(productionWebpackConfig, {
        output: {
            filename: "js/[name].[fullhash].min.js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, config.get("appPath")),
            publicPath: host
        },
        entry: {
            // polyfills: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src", "polyfills/polyfills"),
            application: "production",
            vendor: ["react", "react-dom", "redux-saga", "react-redux", "redux-json-router", "redux", "axios",
                "lodash", "highcharts"],
            extras: ["extras"],
            legacySignIn: path.join(__dirname, "../src/StaticPage/resources/js/index.js")
        },
        plugins,
        module: {
            //noParse: /\.min\.js$/,
            rules: [
                // Sass
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    include: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../src")],
                    use: [
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                modules: true,
                                importLoaders: 2,
                                context: __dirname,
                                localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "resolve-url-loader"
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "postcss-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                                plugins: () => [
                                    require("autoprefixer")({
                                        browsers: ["last 2 versions"]
                                    }),
                                    require("cssnano")({
                                        zindex: false,
                                        reduceIdents: {
                                            keyframes: false
                                        }
                                    })
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: "sass-loader",
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        }
                    ]

                }
            ]
        },
        externals: {
            recurly: "recurly"
        }
    });

    return merge(baseWebpackConfig, productionWebpackConfig);
};
```

also package.json

I tied using upgrading HtmlWebPackPlugin to latest version and all plugins to latest. Also remove unwanted plugins as well.

Not sure waht I am missing, please help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks